# Get User Ranking based on points from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I have a function in my model of my codeigniter application that returns a list of rows in descending order of points. This is done to get the rows with the hihgest points.

```
public function top_points()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('points', 'desc'); 
        $query=$this->db->get('player', 50);
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
```

This work fine in returning the data for the highest 50 points.

However I would like to find the position/rank of a particular player in the `Player` table which I am querying. I would like to a specific player by an `id`.

```
public function get_player_rank($player_id)
    {
            $this->db->where('player_id', $palyer_id); 
        $this->db->order_by('points', 'desc'); 
        $query=$this->db->get('player');
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
```

I would like to use something like this to get the position of a player specified by his $id. Like a ranking in terms of his points earned.

How do i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
$sql = " 
SET @rownum=0;
SELECT player_id, rank 
FROM (
      SELECT player_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank FROM  `player` 
      ORDER BY  `points` DESC
     ) AS D
WHERE D.player_id=?";

$result = $this->db->query($sql,array($palyer_id))->row_array();
```

OR you could try

```
$sql = " 
         SELECT player_id, rank 
         FROM (
                SELECT player_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank
                FROM  `player` , (SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r
                ORDER BY  `points` DESC
              ) AS D
         WHERE D.player_id=?";
$result = $this->db->query($sql,array($palyer_id))->row_array();
```

Comment: There is no `rank` column in my table. There is the `points` column with the accumulated points.

Comment: the rank column provides you with the rank. its just an alias of user defined variable @rownum

Comment: When I try the first option I get error "A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT fb_id, rank FROM ( SELECT fb_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank F' at line 2

SET @rownum=0; SELECT fb_id, rank FROM ( SELECT fb_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank FROM `User` ORDER BY `points` DESC ) AS D WHERE D.fb_id='832357449'"

Comment: My function: `public function my_rank($id)
 {
  
$sql = " 
SET @rownum=0;
SELECT fb_id, rank 
FROM (
      SELECT fb_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank FROM  `User` 
      ORDER BY  `points` DESC
     ) AS D
WHERE D.fb_id=?";

$result = $this->db->query($sql,array($id))->row_array();
  
 }
`

Comment: Try the second query its a single query.. meanwhile i will check the first query in codeignitor and let you know the response. Both queries works fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried the second, and I dont get that error, but how do I call values from the function. I want to show the name of the user(player). I tried a fro each where I called the player's information as  $me['username']; but it doesn't recognize it. How do I check the data from this function such as the player's name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45809/discussion-between-nouphal-m-and-tester)